# Best HTTP code for a failure of an external subsystem

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I am working on a system that exposes a REST API. My system, to fulfill some of the requests, needs to call external APIs. These APIs sometimes fail (with internal server errors) and these failures prevent my system for completing the operation successfully.

What is the best HTTP status code that my system should return? I would like to distinguish the failures of external systems from internal failures of my system thus I am not particularly happy with returning 500.

Comment: 503 - Service unavailable for external errors and 500 for internal? Or 504 - Gateway Timeout for external errors.

Comment: but this still does not distinguish between my system and its dependencies.

Comment: It does, if the error code returned is 503/504 for external calls that fails and 500 for internal calls that fails there's your distinction. I.e you build it into your application to take a 500 from an external call and return it as a 503/504 to your client.

Comment: @JaggenSWE definitely **not** [503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4), because it means "temporary overloading or maintenance of the server".

Answer (score 13):

For these cases I prefer HTTP 502:

> 10.5.3 502 Bad Gateway
>
> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.

Although it technically is more suitable for proxies, I think it's the closest you can get to distinguishing a server error (500) from an upstream server error.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to consider returning [HTTP 504](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#504) in case a request to an external system timed out:

> **504 Gateway Timeout**
>   The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and
>   did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

Comment: What I encounter is usually a failure (error 500), not a timeout

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying that you might want to _distinguish_ a failure from a timeout in case it would happen :)